# How to operate with more than 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css, switch-statement, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator with HTML, CSS and JS but I can't fix how to operate for example 1 + 2 + 3. Right now I'm getting 5 as a result with my actual code and the correct result should be 6. Here you have all my JS. Hope someone can help me. If you need the HTML let me know!

I want to operate with more than 2 numbers.

```js
let operacion1;
let operacion2;
let performance;

const iniciamosCalculadoraPRO = () => {
  let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
  let reset = document.getElementById("reset");
  let suma = document.getElementById("suma");
  let minus = document.getElementById("minus");
  let multi = document.getElementById("multi");
  let divi = document.getElementById("divi");
  let equal = document.getElementById("equal");
  let root = document.getElementById("root");
  let one = document.getElementById("one");
  let two = document.getElementById("two");
  let three = document.getElementById("three");
  let four = document.getElementById("four");
  let five = document.getElementById("five");
  let six = document.getElementById("six");
  let seven = document.getElementById("seven");
  let eight = document.getElementById("eight");
  let nine = document.getElementById("nine");
  let cero = document.getElementById("cero");
};


one.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "1";
};
two.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "2";
};
three.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "3";
};
four.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "4";
};
five.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "5";
};
six.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "6";
};
seven.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "7";
};
eight.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "8";
};
nine.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "9";
};
cero.onclick = function() {
  resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + "0";
};
reset.onclick = function() {
  resCalculator();
};
suma.onclick = function() {
  operacion1 = resultado.textContent;
  performance = "+";
  clearAll();
};
minus.onclick = function() {
  operacion1 = resultado.textContent;
  performance = "-";
  clearAll();
};
multi.onclick = function() {
  operacion1 = resultado.textContent;
  performance = "*";
  clearAll();
};
divi.onclick = function() {
  operacion1 = resultado.textContent;
  performance = "/";
  clearAll();
};
equal.onclick = function() {
  operacion2 = resultado.textContent;
  showingResults();
};

root.onclick = function() {
  operacion1 = resultado.textContent;
  rootOperation();
}

punto.onclick = function() {
  if (!resultado.textContent.includes(".")) {
    resultado.textContent = resultado.textContent + ".";
  }
}




const clearAll = () => {
  resultado.textContent = "";
}

const resCalculator = () => {
  resultado.textContent = "";
  operacion1 = 0;
  operacion2 = 0;
  performance = "";
}

const rootOperation = () => {
  resultado.textContent = Math.sqrt(operacion1).toFixed(3);
}



const showingResults = () => {
  let resultadosGlobales = 0;
  switch (performance) {
    case "+":
      resultadosGlobales = parseFloat(operacion1) + parseFloat(operacion2);
      break;

    case "-":
      resultadosGlobales = parseFloat(operacion1) - parseFloat(operacion2);
      break;

    case "*":
      resultadosGlobales = parseFloat(operacion1) * parseFloat(operacion2);
      break;

    case "/":
      resultadosGlobales = parseFloat(operacion1) / parseFloat(operacion2);
      break;
  }
  resCalculator();
  resultado.textContent = resultadosGlobales;
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", iniciamosCalculadoraPRO);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #7A99B9;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.calculadora {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(156.9deg, #3E566B 0%, #21384E 100.39%);
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 365px;
  height: 570px;
  box-shadow: 8px 7px 19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.calculadora td button {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #D8D8D8;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#resultado {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #BBC4B1;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

button {
  background: #536576;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #6C849B;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="calculadora">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><span id="resultado"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td><button id="reset">C</button></td>
      <td><button id="root">√</button></td>
      <td><button id="divi">/</button></td>
      <td><button id="multi">*</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="seven">7</button></td>
      <td><button id="eight">8</button></td>
      <td><button id="nine">9</button></td>
      <td><button id="minus">-</button></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="four">4</button></td>
      <td><button id="five">5</button></td>
      <td><button id="six">6</button></td>
      <td><button id="suma">+</button></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="one">1</button></td>
      <td><button id="two">2</button></td>
      <td><button id="three">3</button></td>
      <td><button id="equal">=</button></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><button id="cero">0</button></td>
      <td><button id="punto">.</button></td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, please update the snippet I made you with relevant HTML in a [mcve]

Comment: Also I STRONGLY suggest you look at delegation. No need to have a function per button

Comment: @mplungjan I have already updated. I'm sorry if it's not the correct way to updated but I'm quite new in here...

Comment: You did ok, I removed unnecessary HTML and changed the onload to `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", iniciamosCalculadoraPRO);`  to make it run

Comment: You can start with `document.querySelector('.calculadora').addEventListener('click', function(e) { const tgt = e.target; const id = tgt.id; const val = tgt.textContent; console.log(id, val); });` then you can cut 90% of the code and assignments and go from there using the dupe I posted

Comment: Then remove clearAll() from most of the clicks and only show a result when ppl click = for example